# How can I link tests and store test results from my stand alone Watir framework in TFS

Tags: tfs, rake, watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects

I have a very robust Watir framework that I execute via rake.
My company uses TFS and wants to be able to link and trace test scenarios and results back into TFS.  Is there any good way of doing this?  Or migrating the whole framework INTO TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way or integration tool to achieve what you want.

If you want to link test and store test results into TFS. You may have to give up the framework. [Create tests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/test/create-tests-vs) and [integrate test with build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138(v=vs.120).aspx), [track your test results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282443.aspx) in TFS.